# How to configure headless Chromedriver to emulate a device with hover?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

In my application, some element should only be present when the device supports hover. Therefore, I use the following CSS:

```
@media(hover: none) {
  #present-only-if-device-supports-hover {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

For testing this with Capybara, I’d like to emulate a device with hover. So far I could only get it working in non-headless mode.

I use the following check:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('#present-only-if-device-supports-hover', visible: true)
```

With driver `:selenium_chrome`, the check passes. However, with driver `:selenium_chrome_headless`, the check fails because the element is not visible.

(As a side note: `Capybara::Node::Element#hover` works with both drivers.)

I tried a few things which didn’t change this behavior:

- I enabled device emulation with `options.add_emulation(device_metrics: {width: 800, height: 800, pixelRatio: 1, touch: false})`, as it seems like disabling touch enables hover. Indeed, changing `:touch` to `true` made it stop working in non-headless mode. But in headless mode, neither works.
- I tried to set the `webkit.webprefs.available_hover_types` and `webkit.webprefs.primary_hover_type` preferences (which I found during a Chromium code inspection) to `1`, but it didn’t have any effect. I also tried leaving off the `webkit.webprefs.` prefix.

More suggestions?